# LINQ expression to extract only two word phrases

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list (of objects), with one property in the object as a string.

This property always contains single words and would like to loop through all sequential combinations in pairs, for example:

- word1
- word2
- word3
- word4
- word5

I am trying to write LINQ which will allow me to iterate through the data in the following format:

- word1 [space] word2
- word2 [space] word3
- word3 [space] word4
- word4 [space] word5

Could anybody suggest the most efficient way of doing this.

I have a bunch of conditional IF statements at the moment that I'm looking to remove.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var pairs = words.Zip(words.Skip(1), (x, y) => x + " " + y);
```

That's assuming you're using .NET 4, which is when [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) was introduced.

Comment: If not on .Net 4, Jon Skeet can still help.  See [Zip](http://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/Zip.cs) from Jon Skeet's [EduLinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) series.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TOutput, TOutput>> Pairwise<TInput, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<TInput> collection, Func<TInput, TOutput> func)
{
  using (var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator()) 
  {
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) yield break;
    TOutput first = func(enumerator.Current);
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
      TOutput second = func(enumerator.Current);
      yield return Tuple.Create(first, second);
      first = second;
    }
  }
}
```

Which would be useable like so:

```
IEnumerable<string> pairs = yourCollection.Pairwise(element => element.Property).Select(t => t.Item1 + ' ' + t.Item2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using .NET 4 and implemented Jon's answer.